# Evaluate list queries inside `HoldForm[]` terms

Tags: evaluation, latex

When I have an equation like (example)...

[image]

...I can derived it and turn it into `TeXForm` afterwards (that is what I want). Therefore, I might want to additionaly display it as an equation - as described in the last lines. Thus, I have to use `HoldForm` since I do not want to evaluate but just want to display it. Here, the operation that I want to show in $\LaTeX$ is an derivation and implicite definition.

If I have more parameters then $(x,y,z)$ it might come in handy to use a list `varlist` to store my variables and then derive the function considering another variable during each iteration. Thus, I take `varlist[[i]]` as my argument for the derivation of $f$. Obviously, $i$ is my loop variable. The exact same derivative of $f$ - considering $x$ in this case - should be expressed through...

[image]

But as you can see, the list's name and $i$ as an argument are kept and the list is not evaluated at position $i$ so that $x$ does not appear in my final `TeXForm`. How to evaluate my list correctly while `HoldForm` is active?

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
With[{i = varlist[[1]]},
   TeXForm[HoldForm[D[f[x, y, z], x] = i]]
]
```

`With` holds all of the functions, searches through them, and replaces them before evaluating anything, and can therefore bypass `HoldForm`.